# gt 54om isnt being used when playing games

Tags: games

so I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and after looking everywhere on how to install steam, I download tf2 and its lagging and has no AA, so i check and im not using my real gpu, instead im using my intel integrated gpu, HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to install the relevant drivers for your graphics card.

Follow this : https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/

And good luck :)